# SQL - select limit column2 values for distinct column 1

Tags: sql, sqlite, unique

I have

```
name:      date:
Mike       02-10-14
Will       03-31-18
Charlie    04-21-18
Mike       05-31-18
Will       04-11-17
Charlie    04-15-18
Mike       08-02-17
Will       09-16-18
Charlie    04-12-17
...        ...
```

I want, for each name, the most recent (2) dates in desc order.

```
name:     date:
Mike      05-31-18
Mike      08-02-17
Will      09-16-18
Will      03-31-18
Charlie   04-21-19
Charlie   04-15-19
```

I have been trying various group by / order by / max / desc / unique / distinct methods but cannot find the solution that keeps all the names. My attempts keep grabbing the 2 most recent dates in the entire table instead of per person.

Current attempt:

```
SELECT NAME, DATE FROM SIGHTINGS ORDER BY SIGHTED DESC LIMIT 2;
```

--returns 2 most recent dates of entire table

Comment: This will help you.  http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/how-to/get_top_n_each_group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work because it sorts by reformatting your dates to `YY-MM-DD`:

```
SELECT  
  t.NAME, t.DATE 
FROM SIGHTINGS AS t 
WHERE
  t.DATE IN (
    SELECT 
      DATE 
    FROM SIGHTINGS 
    WHERE SIGHTINGS.NAME = t.NAME
    ORDER BY SUBSTR(DATE, 7, 2) || '-' || SUBSTR(DATE, 1, 5) DESC LIMIT 2 
  )
ORDER BY t.NAME, SUBSTR(t.DATE, 7, 2) || '-' || SUBSTR(t.DATE, 1, 5) DESC;
```

Comment: @user4888 . . . I don't see why the date format is an issue if the query in your question works.

Comment: @GordonLinoff since the date is `TEXT` in sqlite and the format in the table is `MM-DD-YY` doesn't it need to be reformatted to `YY-MM-DD` before any sorting?

Comment: @forpas . . . The OP says that the query at the end returns the two most recent dates.  That query would not work if the dates were strings (at least with the sample data in the question).  That's why I asked the OP the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the question has the `sqlite3` tag, so it's obvious that the dates are strings. Seeing a value like `05-31-18` I conclude that the format is `MM-DD-YY`, so I used the reformatting.

Answer (score 1):

A **Window Function** with the **Partition By** clause would be most appropriate here: https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html. Scroll down to "2.2. The PARTITION BY Clause", also check out row_number() and rank() further down on the same page.

Below is the code, untested as I have no access to a sqlite db. So the syntax might be slightly off. My most familiar one is SQL Server.

```
SELECT t.name, 
       t.date
FROM 
(
    SELECT name,
           date,
           row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date DESC) AS recency
) as t
WHERE t.recency <= 2
ORDER BY t.name, t.date DESC
```

Btw, the window/partition concept is general in SQL. I believe SQL Server and Oracle have almost identical syntax.

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you!